# Error : package 'rJava' could not be loaded but library(rJava) is working

Tags: r, mongodb

I've 64 bit machine and have installed jdk and jre(64 bit) also R and R studio is 64bit. I'm trying to install 'rMongodb' package by:

```
devtools::install_github("tc/RMongo")
```

but it gives out error

```
  Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rJava':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/saini/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rJava/libs/i386/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Error : package 'rJava' could not be loaded
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
Warning: package 'rJava' was built under R version 3.5.2
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
* removing 'C:/Users/saini/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/RMongo'
In R CMD INSTALL
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/saini/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpuEHfqO/file20f419985c01/RMongo_0.1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Even though `library(rJava)` works fine.
Ps. I've already set the environment variables.

Comment: looks like there is some msmatch in 32bit and 64bit

Comment: I think so but library(rJava) works fine.

Comment: Have you tried reconfiguring in shell `R CMD javareconf`

Comment: it doesn't recognize javareconf argument